# Difference between BarEntry and RadarEntry when added to a DataSet asynchronously

Tags: android, firebase, mpandroidchart

I am working on two different charts, one is a RadarChart that compares the scores of all "categories" in an "assessment" to other "assessments", and a grouped BarChart that allows the user to select "categories" in an "assessment" and compare them to other "assessments". The data is pulled from Firebase and the `DatabaseReferences` are stored in an `ArrayList`. My RadarChart uses the following code and displays the following result:

```
        ArrayList<RadarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<IRadarDataSet> allDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < assessmentKeys.size(); i++) {
            final ArrayList<RadarEntry> radarEntries = new ArrayList<>();
            final int trackerIndex = i;
            dataSets.add(trackerIndex, new RadarDataSet(radarEntries, assessmentName.get(i)) );
            mAssessmentCategoryRefs.get(i).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Category category = postSnapshot.getValue(Category.class);
                            radarEntries.add(new RadarEntry((float)category.getCategoryScore(), category.getNumber() - 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomR = random.nextInt(256);
            int randomG = random.nextInt(256);
            int randomB = random.nextInt(256);
            dataSets.get(trackerIndex).setColor(Color.rgb(randomR, randomG, randomB));
            dataSets.get(trackerIndex).setFillColor(Color.rgb(randomR, randomG, randomB));
            dataSets.get(trackerIndex).setDrawFilled(true);
            allDataSets.add(dataSets.get(trackerIndex));
        }

        RadarData data = new RadarData(allDataSets);
```

[image: 1]

Because `RadarEntry`, `BarEntry`, `BarDataSet`, `RadarDataSet`, `IBarDataSet`, and `IRadarDataSet` all share parent classes between them, I assumed that I would be able to load data into a grouped BarChart in the same manner that I did with the RadarChart. For a proof of concept, I used the following code to verify that it will work before attempting to pull from Firebase:

```
        final ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<IBarDataSet> allDataSets = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int j = 0; j < assessmentKeys.size(); j++ ) {
                final int jTracker = j;
                final ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
                dataSets.add(j, new BarDataSet(entries, assessmentName.get(j)));
                Log.d("Received_Data", "Getting data for " + assessmentName.get(j));

                for(int k = 0; k < categoryNames.size(); k++) {
                    entries.add(new BarEntry(k, k+1));
                }

                Random random = new Random();
                int randomR = random.nextInt(256);
                int randomG = random.nextInt(256);
                int randomB = random.nextInt(256);
                dataSets.get(j).setColor(Color.rgb(randomR, randomG, randomB));
                allDataSets.add(dataSets.get(j));
            }
```

This produced this chart:
[image: 2]

When I add code to pull from firebase, something weird happens that does not happen with the RadarChart:

```
            final ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<IBarDataSet> allDataSets = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int j = 0; j < assessmentKeys.size(); j++ ) {
                final int jTracker = j;
                final ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
                dataSets.add(j, new BarDataSet(entries, assessmentName.get(j)));
                Log.d("Received_Data", "Getting data for " + assessmentName.get(j));

                for(int k = 0; k < categoryNames.size(); k++) {
                    final String categoryName = categoryNames.get(k);
                    final int kTracker = k;
                    mAssessmentCategoryRefs.get(jTracker).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    Category category = postSnapShot.getValue(Category.class);
                                    if(categoryName.equals(category.getName())) {
                                        entries.add(new BarEntry(kTracker, (float)category.getCategoryScore()));
                    Log.d(TAG, "Added " + category.getName() + " to entries");
                                    } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Skipped " + category.getName());
                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                }

                Random random = new Random();
                int randomR = random.nextInt(256);
                int randomG = random.nextInt(256);
                int randomB = random.nextInt(256);
                dataSets.get(j).setColor(Color.rgb(randomR, randomG, randomB));
                allDataSets.add(dataSets.get(j));
            }
            BarData data = new BarData(allDataSets);
            mBarChart.setData(data);
            data.notifyDataChanged();
            mBarChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mBarChart.invalidate();
```

[image: 3] 
The data is not charted, even though my logs show that it correctly skips categories that dont match a selected name and adds the category's score if it does.

What is the cause of this? At first I thought that it may be due to the async nature of the data being pulled from firebase, but if that were the case, my RadarChart would experience the same issue. As far as I can tell the only real difference between `RadarEntry` and `BarEntry` is that the index is the second argument in a `RadarEntry` but the first in a `BarEntry`.The entries are loaded into the `DataSet` in the same manner, the `DataSet`s are loaded into the `ArrayList<IBarDataSet>` in the same manner, yet for some reason one works and the other does not. Does anyone know what the issue is? Is this a bug with `MPAndroidChart`'s explicit `BarEntry`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. First, I had to create an initialization method that is called in `onCreate()`:

```java
    private Map<String, Map<String, Float>> assessmentData = new HashMap<>();
    private void initAssessmentData() {
        for(int i = 0; i < assessmentKeys.size(); i++) {
            final Map<String, Float> categoryNameScore = new HashMap<>();
            mAssessmentCategoryRefs.get(i).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Category category = postSnapShot.getValue(Category.class);
                            categoryNameScore.put(category.getName(), (float) category.getCategoryScore());
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
            assessmentData.put(assessmentKeys.get(i), categoryNameScore);
        }
    }
```

Then to put the data into the graph I just had to change my code to this:

```java
final ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<IBarDataSet> allDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            final BarData data = new BarData(allDataSets);

            for(int j = 0; j < assessmentKeys.size(); j++ ) {
                final int jTracker = j;
                final ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
                dataSets.add(j, new BarDataSet(entries, assessmentName.get(j)));
                Log.d("Received_Data", "Getting data for " + assessmentName.get(j));


                for(String key : assessmentData.keySet()) {
                    if(key.equals(assessmentKeys.get(j))) {
                        Map<String, Float> categoryData = assessmentData.get(key);
                        for(String key2 : categoryData.keySet()) {
                            if(categoryNames.contains(key2)) {
                                entries.add(new BarEntry(categoryNames.indexOf(key2), categoryData.get(key2)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Random random = new Random();
                int randomR = random.nextInt(256);
                int randomG = random.nextInt(256);
                int randomB = random.nextInt(256);
                dataSets.get(j).setColor(Color.rgb(randomR, randomG, randomB));
                allDataSets.add(dataSets.get(j));
                data.notifyDataChanged();
                mBarChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mBarChart.invalidate();
```

[image: 1]